# Selection Sort Strings

Tags: java, string, sorting, selection-sort

I read a file with cities and its population and I am trying to sort the cities alphabetically using a selection sort.
The issue is that for some reason it sorts it in an odd way. The order of the "sorted" list is "ABDCEFHG..." I tried following it but I can't understand where it messes up. This is the code:

```
    //Selection
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size() - 1; i++) 
    {
        int minPos = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cities.size(); j++) 
        {
            if (cities.get(j).compareToIgnoreCase(cities.get(minPos)) < -1)
                minPos = j;
        }
        swap(cities, minPos, i);
    }
    System.out.print("\nSelection: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++)
        System.out.print(cities.get(i) +"|");

private static void swap(ArrayList <String> a, int i, int j) 
{
    String temp = a.get(i);
    a.set(i, a.get(j));
    a.set(j, temp);
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `... < 0` instead of `... < -1`?

Comment: why are you using <-1? you should be using <0

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. It was the first time I used string comparison so I am kind of new with it. Thank you!

Comment: your welcome. I would reccomend that you read the javadoc for the compareTo methods so you fully understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, your problem is almost certainly your `... < -1` comparison, which is essentially meaningless in the context of comparators.  As documented in [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), comparisons in Java are generally done by returning

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

[`String.compareToIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) follows the same rule:

> ```
> Returns:
>     a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the specified
>     String is greater than, equal to, or less than this String, ignoring
>     case considerations.
> ```

These contracts intentionally say nothing about what those negative or positive numbers might be, and so implementations are able to do whatever is easiest.  Many implementations will explicitly return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, but others, including those in `String`, use subtraction as a shortcut, returning the difference between the items being compared, e.g. `x.compareTo(y)` does `return x-y`.  If `x` and `y` are the same, the result is `0`, otherwise it returns a negative number if `x` is smaller, and a positive number if `x` is larger.

In short, you must always use `0` as your comparison point.